# Android 5 SD card label

Tags: android

When I send ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent I can see some kind of SD card label.
How I can get it in my application?

[image: SD card label]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send this intent using startActivityForResult method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

After that you can get the uuid in your onActivityResult method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri treeUri = intent.getData();
    final int splitIndex = treeId.indexOf(':', 1);
    final String uuid = treeId.substring(0, splitIndex);
}
```

uuid is the text, that your are looking for.

If you need to get uuid of all storages, without showing documents tree picker, you can use StorageManager. But getVolumeList, and getUuid methods are hidden so I used reflection to get it.

```
    StorageManager mStorageManager = (android.os.storage.StorageManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

        Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");

        Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
        Method getUuid = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getUuid");
        Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);

        final int length = Array.getLength(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
            String uuid = (String) getUuid.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
        }
```

Comment: This method will work on on Android Version >= 24, Storage Volumes are introduced in Android 24